# Is it possible to override an include file from a project dependency

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a project that uses includes from other projects. This works fine, however one of the includes references a file that I would like to somehow overwrite.

Is this possible? If I include a file with the same name in my project will that somehow overwrite it on compilation? Unfortunately I don't have write access to that file, so I need to find a work around and substitute my own file. This is with Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Use Pre-Build Event to make override include file.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Overwriting an include file could lead to various problems. Maybe there is a better, or correct way to solve that.

Comment: There isn't when I don't have write access to these files. We are trying to maintain compatability unfortunately

Comment: @joequest1 a header (if it is not a header-only library) belongs to a compiled binary. If you change anything in it then you most likely introduce other problems. `[…]There isn't when I don't have write access to these files.[…]` if you don't say **what** you need to change, it is neither possible to tell you if those changes are valid nor if there are better ways to do that. So my question was about what you try to accomplish, what kind of changes do you want to perform in the header to ensure compatibility?

Comment: so the inherited library accesses a singleton class which I essentially just need to pull functionality out of (not removing methods or members). I include a specific header which contains a class, which i then initalize and call a function on.. that function calls that singelton logging class

Comment: my goal was to somehow compile over that original header (which will already be compiled) and somehow remove functionality

Comment: if I could I'd just go in and modify the logic, but because I am using an included library that I am restricted from modifying, I need to find another way to replace the .h and .cpp of that file

Comment: It is hard to follow your explanation and to get an overall view. But this really sounds like you might introduce some unpredictable behavior there, especially if the already compiled parts of that library makes usage of the same singleton or other parts of that head. The linker might not even complain about that, but it could - even if it might initially work - mess things up badly at any later point of your development process. I  had such a situation when I accidentally link against two different versions of the same header-only library, that only had slight changes in the functions.

Comment: So you really need to be sure that your changes are valid according to the specs and won't introduce UB.

Answer (score 0):

Put your header file directory to beggining of your include search path "Additional Include Directories". So compiler will find your header file first.